# Как менять цвет кнопки в зависимости от фона?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пишу на React. На странице у меня есть кнопка прокрутки вверх.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При прокрутке на некоторых блоках ее не видно из-за того, что цвета совпадают.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы при соприкосновении с определенными блоками, такого же цвета что и кнопка, она становилась белой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отследить соприкосновение кнопки с определенным блоком? Какие слушатели ставить?

Comment: Наиболее корректным решением такой проблемы будет дизайнерская оптимизация. То есть, лучше подобрать подходящие цвета, чем пытаться выловить событие перекрытия двух элементов разметки динамически. Потому что нет такого события, которое сообщило бы, что два элемента разметки пересклись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с использованием [mix-blend-mode](https://caniuse.com/?search=mix-blend-mode)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.section.js-trigger {
  background-color: #316AE3;
}

.btn-up {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 24px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section js-trigger"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section js-trigger"></section>
<section class="section"></section>

<a href="#" class="btn-up">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
            <path d="M214.6 41.4c-12.5-12.5-32.8-12.5-45.3 0l-160 160c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.8 0 45.3s32.8 12.5 45.3 0L160 141.2V448c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32s32-14.3 32-32V141.2L329.4 246.6c12.5 12.5 32.8 12.5 45.3 0s12.5-32.8 0-45.3l-160-160z"/>
        </svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

внутри класса блока переопределить свойства класса кнопки

Comment: Вероятно, имеется в виду, что кнопка плавающая и следует за прокруткой страницы. И в некоторые моменты прокрути попадает на фон, который сливается с фоном этой кнопки.

Comment: Это не было написано явно, если это действительно так, то это решение конечно же не будет хорошим.